# How do I make Google Maps controls responsive?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, responsive-design

I am working on my first full-page map screen. I am adding a couple custom controls on the map. One being a legend, the other a way to query our system and place pins on the map. I have been able to place the controls on map and it works well. I have one in the TOP_RIGHT and one in the TOP_LEFT. I would like to make this responsive now. I would like the legend to take up the entire bottom of the map, and the inquiry control to go to the top. I can't find anything on how to make this responsive. How do I go about accomplishing this? Online resources would be great.

**Update:** I realized I didn't make this clear. On PC/tablet, I want the legend in the upper right and on the phone, I want this to be all the way across. Similar to how [this page](http://www.citycentermankato.com/city-center/stay/) works.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple, set the width of the HTML-elements to `100%`.

Be sure that these controls dont overlap with the default-controls.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/16r1777q/